# sacar la palabra mas repetida de un array en javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un array de palabras y me gustaría con javascript sacar una variable con la palabra mas repetida pero no consigo encontrar como hacerlo.

ejemplo de array

```html
var array = ["uno","uno","dos","tres",]
```

tengo que sacar la palabras más repetida y pasarla a una variable haber si alguien me puede ayudar gracias.

el resultado tiene que ser:

```html
var palabra_repetida = "Uno";
```

Comment: Hola, antes agrega el código que has intentado por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probá con esta función que la encontré en un foro y me parece bastante simple de leer y favorece el código limpio:

```
function mode(arr){
  return arr.sort((a,b) =>
    arr.filter(v => v===a).length
    - arr.filter(v => v===b).length
  ).pop();
}
```

Devuelve el elemento del array que más se repite, por ende podrías hacer:

```
var palabra_repetida = mode(array)
```

Espero haber resultado de ayuda.

Comment: Deberías poner el enlace de la fuente original para darle créditos al autor original

Comment: te pones la gorra Aprendiz, dedicate a lavar los platos. Acá tenes el enlace >> http://www.homerswebpage.com/

Answer (score 0):

La forma que te dice @user134205 esta genial , super limpio, pero por si te ayuda , aquí te dejo otra forma de hacerlo:

```js
function verificarRepetido(){
  var palabras = ["uno","uno","dos","tres",];
  var contador=0;
  var mayor=1;
  var indiceMayor=0;

    for(i=0;i<palabras.length;i++){
      contador=0;
      for(j=0;j<palabras.length;j++){
        if(palabras[i]==palabras[j]){
         contador=contador+1;
        }
      }
      
      if(contador>mayor){
        indiceMayor=i;
      }
    }
    
    alert("El que mas se repite es " + palabras[indiceMayor]);

}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="verificarRepetido();return false;" value="Ver"/>
```

Espero te sirva :)